# Transform the form of the function's result and get the maximum value

Tags: r, function, chi-squared

```
library(CHAID)
data("USvote")
functionB <- function(z,y)
{
  for (i in 1:length(table(z[,y])))
  {
    n<-paste(names(table(z[,y]))[i])  
    V = paste('vote3')
    Formula <- as.formula(paste(y," ~ ", paste(V)))
    k = aggregate(Formula,data = z[z[,y] %in% c(names(table(z[,y]))[i]),],function(x) length(x))
    print(n)
    print(k)
  }
}
functionB(USvote,'ager')
```

Results:

```
[1] "18-24"
  vote3 ager
1  Gore  379
2  Bush  180
[1] "25-34"
  vote3 ager
1  Gore  728
2  Bush  793
[1] "35-44"
  vote3 ager
1  Gore 1213
2  Bush 1258
[1] "45-54"
  vote3 ager
1  Gore 1168
2  Bush 1004
[1] "55-64"
  vote3 ager
1  Gore  952
2  Bush  844
[1] "65+"
  vote3 ager
1  Gore 1108
2  Bush  988
```

But I want the result like this to be easy to calculate the X-square.

```
ager1 <- aggregate(ager ~ vote3, data = USvote[USvote$ager=="18-24",], function(x) length(x))
ager2 <- aggregate(ager ~ vote3, data = USvote[USvote$ager=="25-34",], function(x) length(x))
ager3 <- aggregate(ager ~ vote3, data = USvote[USvote$ager=="35-44",], function(x) length(x))
ager4 <- aggregate(ager ~ vote3, data = USvote[USvote$ager=="45-54",], function(x) length(x))
ager5 <- aggregate(ager ~ vote3, data = USvote[USvote$ager=="55-64",], function(x) length(x))
ager6 <- aggregate(ager ~ vote3, data = USvote[USvote$ager=="65+",], function(x) length(x))
ager <- cbind(ager1,ager2,ager3,ager4,ager5,ager6)
ager
ager = ager[,-c(3,5,7,9,11)]
colnames(ager) = c("", "18-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65+")
ager
```

Ideal result:

```
      18-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64  65+
1 Gore   379   728  1213  1168   952 1108
2 Bush   180   793  1258  1004   844  988
```

How to transform?
I transformed successfully. But I have a new question now.........
How to get the maximum value of X-square?

```
functionA <- function(x)
{
  for(i in 1:(ncol(x)-1))
  {
    for (j in (i+1):(ncol(x)))
    {
      n<-paste(colnames(x)[i], " vs ", colnames(x)[j], sep="")
      k=chisq.test(cbind(as.numeric((x)[,i]),as.numeric((x)[,j])),correct = FALSE, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 9999)
      s=k$statistic
      print(n)
      print(s)
    }
  }  
}
```

[functionA Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNZsP.png)

Comment: What's the reason to post Images and not text?

Comment: In your function, you're not returning anything; just printing the result. Since you want to save the name of the two groups being tested and their respective X-squared value, you should pre-allocate a vector for names (`VS = character(choose(6, 2))`) and one for X-sq (`Xsq = numeric(choose(6, 2))`) and in each iteration save your "n" and "k" in the respective vector. BTW, it should be more convenient to make your function as a binary (e.g. `myfun = function(x, y) setNames(chisq.test(x, y, ...), paste(x, "VS", y))`) and use `combn` to apply your function to all combinations of your column.

Comment: @WernerHenze Because it will be disorder......I do not know the reason,too.......

Comment: @ZheZhang Please post text as text and read the help pages for how to format the text. Posting code is quite simple: paste it, mark it and select the "{}" icon.

Comment: @WernerHenze Thanks for the remind. I have edited.

Comment: all you need is `with(USvote,table(vote3,ager))` ...

Comment: @BenBolker It works!!!!!!  Thanks verrrrrrry much!!!!!!

Comment: a lesson in the value of posting reproducible examples ...

Comment: @BenBolker Could u help me solve the new problem?thx

Comment: ask another question and see what happens

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can extract X-square statistic this way:

```
chisq.test(c(89,37,30,28,2), c(40,20,20,15,5)) -> test
test$statistic

# X-squared 
#        15
```

And than just find the maximum value. But it would be easier to help if your example were reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I used the functionA(ager) to run out the result. The "functionA(ager)$statistic" is not working. Do u know how to solve it?

Comment: @ZheZhang Ask a question with a minimal and reproducible example.